# Laravel Subdirectory project not accessible after SSL setup

Tags: php, laravel, apache, ssl

I am hosting the React JS project in the root directory as homepage and Laravel project in sub-folder. Previously before SSL setup, I was able to access the Laravel project from sub-folder but after SSL setup I am not able to access the Laravel project from sub-folder. Below is my `apache.conf` file setup after SSL setup.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.xxx.com.np
ServerAlias www.xxx.com.np
Redirect permanent / https://xxx.com.np/

<Directory "/var/www/xxx/html">
    Options Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.xxx.com.np
ServerAlias www.xxx.com.np
DocumentRoot /var/www/xxx/html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/xxx/key/myserver.key
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/xxx/certs/xxx.crt
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/xxx/certs/xxx.ca-bundle


<Directory "/var/www/xxx/html">
    Options Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Directory Structure in the server.

/var/www/xxx/html   => React Project

/var/www/xxx/html/folder => folder has Laravel Project

/var/www/xxx//html/folder1 => folder1 Laravel Project

When I access `xxx.com.np/folder1` then I get the blank page routes of React instead of accessing the Laravel Project at `/folder1` sub-folder